# Can't do substitution in a sed program

Tags: sed, regular-expression

**Q.** I want to write a 2 line program that lets me substitute "the" with "zee" and "The" with "Zee".

**Here is what I'm doing:**

I'm writing a sed program for example, `program.sed`. Inside it, I'm writing

```
s/the/zee/ \\
The/Zee/g
```

Then I'm running `program.sed` like this

```
sed -f program.sed otherfilename
```

**ERROR:**

Unfortunately, error occurs, saying `command garbled: s/the/zee/g`

**NOTE:** If I do change text `c\\` in `sed` with any other commands etc. it works fine, but the problem is with substitution like for example in the above question.

> **EDIT:**

The down solution worked for me the first one before Or, but not the second one. Maybe because the gator version is pretty old. "Oracle Corporation SunOS 5.10 Generic Patch January 2005". `sed` version is very old also "23 July 1998". Just wanted others know.

Comment: @don_crissti, before posting here I even tried that, but it gives the same error.

Comment: @GhostRider which sed version are you using? I tried @don_crissti's suggestion on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` and it worked fine

Comment: In your note, you mention using `c\\ `, but your example code only contains `\\ `. Which is correct, and what do you think that should do?

Comment: @GhostRider which sed version are you using? I can not see how you get that error for that input. (`s/the/zee/g` does not appear in input)

Comment: @spasic well, maybe I think because I'm using gator and its pretty old. Oracle Corporation SunOS 5.10 Generic Patch January 2005. But the down solution worked for me the first one before Or Only.

Comment: do add that info in your question so that it is useful for users visiting this thread.. also add the output of `sed --version` if it is available (or perhaps available in `man sed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `program.sed` you should have:

```
s/the/zee/g; s/The/Zee/g
```

Or:

```
s/the/zee/g
s/The/Zee/g
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for completing my answer mate. I appreciate.

Comment: The first solution above Or worked for me, but the second one did not. Just wanted other's know.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GhostRider My pleasure mate. Thanks for letting us know.